# How to remove matching characters in R?

Tags: r

Seems like an easy question but the solution is alluding me. I'm basically trying to remove matching characters from 2 variables in `R`. The simple code below will hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to do.

If I have 2 variables `x`, `y` and they are filled with characters, like so:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
y <- "C"
```

What I'm trying to do is to search through `x`... and any characters that match the characters in `y`, I want to remove from `x`. So, in this instance, the only character that matches is `C`... so I want to remove `C` from `x`. Effectively, Im trying to do:

```
x[-3]
```

However, in practise, this method won't work for me. I was trying to achieve this by doing something like:

```
x <- x[,-which(names(x) %in% y)] # This won't work because x is not a data frame with cols
```

or

```
x <- subset(x, select=-y) # this throws back an error saying subset is missing
```

But I can't get these methods to work with characters... any suggestions?

Comment: try `x[!x %in% y]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` doesn't have names, so use `x`, not `names(x)`. Also `x` is a vector, not a data frame, so your extra comma `x[,]` in the brackets won't work.

```
# fix those issues and this:
x[,-which(names(x) %in% y)] 
# becomes this:
x[-which(x %in% y)]

# as phiver points out in comments, `which()` isn't needed, and we can use
x[!x %in% y] 

# many people like to define a "not in" function for this
'%nin%' = Negate(%in%)
x[x %nin% y]
```

Comment: Perfect, so simple when I see the solution. Thanks